# "Mi opresión es tu identidad y tus derechos [...]" vs "Mi opresión es tu identidad y es tus derechos [...]"

Tags: gramática, estilo

No puedo dejar de pensar en [el paralelismo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) en contexto de esta oración, *Mi opresión es tu identidad y tus derechos que no los tengo.*
¿Es correcta esta frase? ¿O sería mejor escribir, p. Ej. en un tweet breve o en una pancarta, uno de los siguientes:

1. *Mi opresión es tu identidad y tus derechos que no los tengo **yo**.*
2. *Mi opresión es tu identidad y **es** tus derechos que no los tengo.*
3. *Mi opresión es tu identidad y **están** tus derechos que no los tengo.*
4. *Mi opresión es tu identidad y **es** tus derechos que no los tengo **yo**.*

Es un comentario amargo de una persona, como yo, que está excluida de la sociedad, p. Ej. de un migrante que percibe su opresión como el precio a pagar por la identidad nacional y los privilegios legales de los nativos. La frase que me inspiró fue la de esta pancarta: *[Mi opresión no es tu identidad](https://twitter.com/movfemmad/status/1396064026703040512).* La persona quiere decir algo como: *Your rights, the rights that I don't have, and your identity are the causes of my oppression* pero si posible en manera más breve - para que se adapte a una pancarta. La persona carece de ambos (la identidad y los derechos) pero siente resentimiento solo por los derechos de los carece.

¿Cuáles de las cinco oraciones son incorrectas?

Comment: Todas las oraciones suenan muy raras y de dudosa gramaticalidad, sobre todo por la duplicidad del objeto directo de la relativa "QUE no LOS tengo". Sería interesante saber cuál es el significado que se desea transmitir para poder arribar a una oración correcta.

Comment: @Gustavson Ya agegue más información a la pregunta en respuesta a su comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre la base de la explicación en el comentario de arriba, no creo que ninguna de las oraciones exprese bien el sentido deseado. No me parece adecuado decir que la opresión de alguien ES xxx, sino SE DEBE A xxx.

Algunas posibles reformulaciones:

- Me oprimen tu identidad y tus derechos, de los que (yo) carezco.
- Tu identidad y tus derechos, de los que (yo) carezco, son la(s) causa(s) de mi opresión.
- Me siento oprimido por tu identidad y tus derechos, de los que (yo) carezco.
- Mi (sentimiento/sensación de) opresión se debe a tu identidad y tus derechos, de los que (yo) carezco.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya me agregue más información a la pregunta en respuesta a ambos tu comentario y a tu respuesta. Si la persona carece de ambos (la identidad y los derechos) pero siente resentimiento solo por los derechos de los carece, 
¿Es correcto decir: *Me oprimen tu identidad y tus derechos, de los derechos que carezco.* ?

Comment: En mis oraciones, "de los que carezco" es ambiguo y puede referirse a identidad y derechos, o solo a derechos. Para que solo se refiera a derechos, deberíamos decir: "Me oprimen tu identidad y tus derechos, derechos de los que carezco".